# how to convert degrees minutes seconds to decimal degrees (python/skyfield)

Tags: python, coordinates, cartopy, satellite, skyfield

I woud like to extract coordinate of a satellite (ISS) in decimal by using this code:

```py
from skyfield.api import EarthSatellite, Topos, load
import time

line1 = '1 25544U 98067A   14020.93268519  .00009878  00000-0  18200-3 0  5082'
line2 = '2 25544  51.6498 109.4756 0003572  55.9686 274.8005 15.49815350868473'

satellite = EarthSatellite(line1, line2, name='ISS (ZARYA)')

while True:
    ts = load.timescale()
    t = ts.now()
    geometry = satellite.at(t)

    subpoint = geometry.subpoint()
    print(subpoint.latitude)
    print('\n')
    print(subpoint.longitude)
    time.sleep(1)
```

The output is a string: `-45deg 44' 13.5"`.

What is the easiest way to convert it to something like: `-77.0089°`?

Comment: Step 1: isolate the three numbers as floats, step 2: do the math.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! This is a platform to help you with something when you get stuck. Please add what have you tried and where did you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Happily, the objects `latitude` and `longitude` are not simple strings, but are fancy angle objects that merely print themselves as 3-part strings to make them easy to read on the screen. You can learn more about them by asking Python for their documentation. At the end of the loop, try adding:

```
help(subpoint.latitude)
```

The documentation for the `Angle` class will come up. You can also find it on the web here:

https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/api-units.html#skyfield.units.Angle

You will want to use the attribute `degrees`, which expresses the angle as a floating point number. Change the print calls in your program to:

```
print(subpoint.latitude.degrees)
print('\n')
print(subpoint.longitude.degrees)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
from skyfield.api import EarthSatellite, Topos, load
import time
line1 = '1 25544U 98067A   14020.93268519  .00009878  00000-0  18200-3 0  5082'
line2 = '2 25544  51.6498 109.4756 0003572  55.9686 274.8005 15.49815350868473'

satellite = EarthSatellite(line1, line2, name='ISS (ZARYA)')

def convert(deg):
  d, m, s = str(deg).replace('deg', '').split(" ")
  ans = float(d) + (float(m.strip("'")) / 60) + (float(s.strip('"')) / 3600)
  return str(ans) + chr(176)

while True:
    ts = load.timescale()
    t = ts.now()
    geometry = satellite.at(t)

    subpoint = geometry.subpoint()
    lat = convert(subpoint.latitude)
    lng = convert(subpoint.longitude)
    print(lat, lng)
    time.sleep(1)
```

**Output:**

```
48.522305555555555° 133.80061111111112°
48.49586111111111° 133.89988888888888°
48.46933333333334° 133.99902777777777°
48.44269444444444° 134.09808333333334°
48.416° 134.19702777777778°
```